# Callback when Cocos2d CCParticleSystem has finished?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I'd like to run a callback/selector when a Cocos2d CCParticleExplosion is completely finished. How do I do this?

I tried using scheduleOnce with the same duration as the emitter, but that finish too soon since I guess the duration of the emitter controls for how long it will emit new particles, but not how long the complete animation lasts.

Answer (score 0):

Try sequencing the action (using CCSequence) with a `CCCAllFunc` Action. After one action runs, the other runs, the CCCAllFunc can be assigned to the selector/method of your choice.

Comment: Not sure I understand? Can I use a particle emitter the same way as an action like CCFadeIn? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is acceptable, but I tested and "it works on my mac".

in CCParticleSystem.h

```
// experimental
typedef void (^onCompletedBlock)();
@property (readwrite, copy) onCompletedBlock onComplete;
```

in CCParticleSystem.m

```
@synthesize onComplete;
```

in the same file update method,

```
_particleCount--;

        if( _particleCount == 0 && self.onComplete)
        {
            [self onComplete]();
            [[self onComplete] release];
        }

if( _particleCount == 0 && _autoRemoveOnFinish ) {
            [self unscheduleUpdate];
            [_parent removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
            return;
}
```

In your code

```
particleSystem.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
particleSystem.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/4);
particleSystem.onComplete = ^
{
    NSLog(@"completed ..");
};
```

again, quite experimental..